# Does dual boot linux need two swap partitions?

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted, swap

My harddrive is partitioned as follows. I used [GParted](http://gparted.org) to gather this info.

---

/dev/sda1 ---- ext4 ---- Ubuntu

---

/dev/sda2 ---- extended

---> /dev/sda5 ---- ext4 ---- Kali

---> /dev/sda6 ---- linux-swap

---

I am assuming that both sda5 and sda6 are both a part of sda2 and it appears to me that the linux-swap is only available to Kali and not Ubuntu. Am I correct in assuming this?

If so, should I create an additional linux-swap for ubuntu under sda1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need separate swap partitions.

You should be able to modify your `/etc/fstab` file in the Ubuntu system to point to the same location as the swap file in the Kali system.  Then both linuxes will use the same partition.